# Modify sparse identity matrix in julia sparse

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

I'm creating an identity sparse matrix because I would like to modify some entries of this matrix:

```
Is = copy(sparse(I, N^2, N^2))
```

However, I got the error (e.g. for `Is[1,3] = -1`)

> ERROR: LoadError: InexactError: Bool(-1.0)

Is there a way I can modify `Is`? I don't want to run two loops of size `N` because this parameter is very big.

Comment: "I got the error" - the code you posted doesn't produce any errors. But code like `Is[1, 2] = -1.0` errors out indeed.

Comment: Haha it also produces errors for sure! ;) `ERROR: UndefVarError: ERROR not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
julia> using SparseArrays, LinearAlgebra

julia> Is = copy(sparse(I, N^2, N^2));

julia> Is[3, 5] = -1.0;
ERROR: InexactError: Bool(-1.0)
Stacktrace:
 [1] Bool
   @ ./float.jl:158 [inlined]
 [2] convert
   @ ./number.jl:7 [inlined]
 [3] _setindex_scalar!(A::SparseMatrixCSC{Bool, Int64}, _v::Float64, _i::Int64, _j::Int64)
   @ SparseArrays ~/Desktop/Julia/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/SparseArrays/src/sparsematrix.jl:2670
 [4] setindex!(A::SparseMatrixCSC{Bool, Int64}, _v::Float64, _i::Int64, _j::Int64)
   @ SparseArrays ~/Desktop/Julia/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/SparseArrays/src/sparsematrix.jl:2667
 [5] top-level scope
   @ REPL[11]:1
```

Looks like `Is` is expected to contain booleans, so Julia attempts to convert `-1.0` to a `Bool`ean and fails. Indeed, `Is` contains booleans:

```
julia> typeof(Is)
SparseMatrixCSC{Bool, Int64}
```

Why is that? Apparently, `I` is `UniformScaling{Bool}`, so `I` is an identity matrix of booleans. You can multiply it by `1.0` to get floats:

```
julia> 1.0*I
UniformScaling{Float64}
1.0*I
```

Then create the new matrix:

```
julia> Is = copy(sparse(1.0*I, N^2, N^2));

julia> eltype(Is)
Float64

julia> Is[3,5] = -1.0;
```